# PHP search form

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP so please forgive if this question or problem seem confusing
I am trying create a search form that has a 2 dropdown option: St. Peter or JHS. the user types in the name of a professor and then choose
the school the professor teach at. the form is has below

```
<form name=form action="form.php" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="find" /> 
<select name="school[]" >
<option value="">School</option>
<option value="1">St.Peter</option>
<option value="2">JHS</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

the form.php script that i am using is

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["find"];
$s=$_GET["school"];
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'peter', 'abc123');

if($q && ($s==St.Peter))
echo "that professor belongs to St.peter H.S";
else{echo "that professor does not belong to this school"; }
elseif($q && ($s==JHS))
echo "that professor belongs to JHS H.S";
else{echo "that professor does not belong to this school"; }
?>
```

when i run this, the output i get is.
that professor belongs to St.peter H.S that professor belongs to JHS H.S

if i change the script just to see if the first if statement is correct eg.

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["find"];
$s=$_GET["school"];
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'peter', 'abc123');

if($q && ($s==St.Peter))
echo "that professor belongs to St.peter H.S";
else{echo "that professor does not belong to this school"; }

?>
```

this echos out that professor belongs to St.peter H.S, but if change

```
if($q && ($s==St.Peter))
```

to

```
if($q && ($s==St.P))
```

it echos out the same thing. this echos out that professor belongs to St.peter H.S,

Comment: Use clean indentations! That is the first rule to learn on programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because what's actually being sent is the "value" of the option, not the text. You should be looking for "1" or "2"

```
if ($q && $s == 1)
```

Comment: if ($1 && $s == 1)
thats off shouldn't like like if ($q && $s == '1')
thanks thou

Answer (score 1):

```
if($q && ($s==St.Peter))
```

This is syntactically incorrect. PHP will see 'St.Peter' as a undefined constant, not a string, you should have

```
if($q && ($s == 'St.Peter'))
```

As well, your big if/else block is incorrect. You have

```
if (...) {
} else {
  ...
} else if {
  ...
}
```

which is a syntax error. an `else` is the final "if all else fails" in an if() series. you cannot follow it up with another else if. The block should be

```
if (...) {
} else if (...) {
} else if (...) }
} else {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must compare with the value of the SELECT OPTION. Try:

```
if($q && ($s=='1'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Marc B. + contagious

```
<select name="school[]" >
```

This instructs PHP to create the GET['school'] parameter as an array. Useful for multiple checkboxes and such.  You should go with

```
<select name="school" >
```